# Restrict Simultaneous login

Tags: php, yii

I'm trying to restrict simultaneous login (same username & pwd) in my yii application, for this I have added one field in user table "login_status". if user is logged-in , login_status = 1  if user logouts properly using application logout icon we are resetting to login_status = 0.

Based on this login_status, we are restricting the simultaneous login(login_status = 1, throwing error "User already connected").

But we are facing issue when user close browser tab or window or system stops abruptly. Always login_status = 1, throwing  the error "User already connected".

Please can anyone help me to solve this issue!!

Answer (score 0):

What about a timeout? If your User hasn´t done any action in let´s say half an hour the session will be closed automatically and the user status is 0 again.
The thing is you have to log when a user is doing any action.
Maybe there is another better solution?

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way for doing that. You need to force server to do some check automatically. You should use something like `Cron Job`. You should have a field like `last_access_date_time` in the table. Every time the user run an action in the system, that field will be updated. Now you need to write an script that run for example every 5 minutes on the server. This script check user `last_access_date_time` for each user, if that field is grater than 5 minutes ago, you should set `login_status = 0` for user. You can search for Cron job to learning **How to run scheduled tasks on the server.**

Comment: You can just log the user's last action as a datetime, then only check this if a user logs in. This way no Cron jobs are needed.

Answer (score 0):

Unless the user is logging out correctly (via button), I can't see how you can force this kind of behaviour without there being some sort of timeout delay. This is assuming that the user would be logging into his account from a different browser & ip. If it's from the same browser or IP you can either use [cookies](http://php.net/manual/en/features.cookies.php) or [php's session data](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php) to stop duplicate logins.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the logged in status every time a logged in user does an action, Also add a datetime to this field. Now you know when a user was last active.
If a new user logs in and the datetime is past your session timeout time you know the user is logged out. And you can login the new user.